# UrlFetch, No response

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to fetch URL using UrlFetchApp.fetch in google-apps-script.

This is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.fastlane.co.il/Mobile.aspx",
                                         {muteHttpExceptions:true});
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I have set a break point on every line of the code and started with debugger. But when I get to the second line, there is nothing in "response" var and the "continue" button just leaves me on this line like it have been loop line.

If I change the URL to "https://www.google.com", everything works ok.

If I change the URL to "https://www.google.com/not-a-real-page", I got an expected exception.

But with the needed URL there is no exception at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your response first in "https://www.fastlane.co.il/Mobile.aspx" service, print your response there first.

Comment: https://www.fastlane.co.il/Mobile.aspx is not responding anything just tried from browsers address bar, taking a long time, no issue with app script url fetch

Comment: @NitinDhomse
Very strange, I can successfully get in to this URL from Israel (from various places and IPs). Maybe it is restricted to only Israeli IPs...
1. How can I check it?
2. Is it possible to use proxy in such situation?

Comment: Ok, but you should verify that, are you getting the response or not, if it is getting then you can get that in app script url fetch as well.

Comment: @NitinDhomse
If I just runing the script, I get an unavailable URL error (or something like this, I have translated the error text because it isn't in english in my google account), but if I run the debugger and starting to press the continue button, I don't get any error. As script getting to the UrlFetchApp line, the behavior like in an endless loop on this line.

Comment: Just hit your service call from browser address bar if it is"Get" request, if "Post" use post requester and verify response, if you are getting the response then your service call is fine, if not then debug in app script url fetch.

Comment: @NitinDhomse, I think it is GET because `curl --get https://www.fastlane.co.il/Mobile.aspx` is working in console

Answer (score 0):

If the url is blocking an IP from outside of your home country then perhaps consider where the URL fetch is originating from. It most likely is originating from the Google's servers in Palo Alto California. I also cannot access that site from my web browser in Korea. I would say the site is blocking the call from America.